# 2013 Linux Clang C++ IDE ... Suggestions For Installations?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, ide

What Installation package would you suggest for both IDE for C++ with CLang on Linux as of now 2013?  Fresh Start.

I would want to test Modern C++ 11 feature complete syntax .  Ease of installation of components is a concern.  Console output is fine for now.  GUI rendering is secondary.
1. IDE  Graphical with the luxury of menus and panels
2. LLVM Clang tool chain

I am aware of SourceForge but I may not understand their summary and documentation to find what I want.  A specific link on which I can click in a web page would be appreciated.

I tend to believe this is a rather ordinary question.  Please tell me if it is not.

I want to experience the more expressive error messages with Clang.  I am not concerned with MS Windows compatibilty.

Thanks for you suggestions.

Comment: Then probably you will be satisfied with using `make`...

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank You. I will change the question to reflect a graphical IDE.  I am not seeking only make at this time.  Or am I?

Comment: I don't know... Personally, I don't use graphical IDEs, and I can say I **am** satisfied with just using `make`, but again, this is entirely my own opinion.

Comment: @H2CO3 Do you have a link to a specific text editor and LLVM binaries that satisfy you?    
Thanks.

Comment: @userXXX I'm using [Gedit](https://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) and the default installation of `clang` that comes with Xcode. (I'm using OS X, not Linux, but you should be able to search which version of `clang` the latest release of Xcode includes, and download that from the LLVM project site.)

Comment: Try [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator). Even though it has "Qt" in its name, it can be used quite fine for pure C++ projects (it is my everyday practice at work, actually). Plus, it is absolutely free, cross-platform (I use it on Linux at home, on OS X at work and even on Windows by occasion) and has a really nice feature of autocompleting the code you write on the fly. Plus, it has a lot of plugins allowing to deal with such project types as Automake, CMake or even some custom build system (my use-case at work), has integration with svn, git and more other features.

Comment: @Dmitry. Balshoi Spaciba.  Does QT easily configure to use CLANG??    I also have a new queston posted about something related I did in the meantime....

Comment: @user3003631 Yes, the configuration is quite easy. For example, once you have installed the LLVM/Clang toolchain (for example, using apt-get on Ubuntu-like Linux distributions), you can open Qt Creator, go to Tools -> Options -> Build & Run, select "Compilers" tab. Clang should already be automatically detected there. Then you go to "Kits" tab, add a new one there and set compiler to Clang. You would probably also need to have some version of Qt framework installed and set it as "Qt version" there if you plan to use default qmake based projects in Qt Creator (which isn't really mandatory).